# Upload linked Revit models for Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

How can I upload a Revit model that contains multiple Revit files, where one of them is a main file and the remaining are linked files into Forge Viewer?

I've uploaded separately and they show as different files in the bucket and the viewer. Can we have one combined file to be viewed in the Forge Viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ZIP file can help you do such thing. You can pack them in a single `.zip` file, then upload it to Forge Data Management Service.

While submitting a translation job to the Forge Model Derivative Service, your job configs should contain two extra parameters `compressedUrn` and `rootFilename`, for example:

```
  {
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA",
     "compressedUrn": true,
     "rootFilename": "myAwesomeHostFile.rvt"
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "2d",
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
  }
```

Afterward, those RVT files will be translated into a single derivative, you can see all linked file contents in the viewer via a single URN.